# MongoDB: fields with a different name but the same meaning

Tags: mongodb, field, grouping

I have a collection of documents with different field name but have the same meaning, and I'm looking for a group by those values.
There's a collection:

```
{
{name="1", age="11"},
{fname="2", age="22"},
{myname="1", age="11"}
}
```

Name, fname and myname represent the same thing and I need to do a group by this field.

I did this, but without good results:

```
    db.aaa.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:{all_name: ["$name","$fname","$myname"]},
    { $project:{
    "all_name": 1,
    "age": 1}}
```

Comment: might be this is a silly aggregation https://mongoplayground.net/p/lUufxZJ9EQt

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet if i have two fields with same problem , i must have project for every case ?

Comment: yes you have to... or you need to optimize your model